# Stripe API opening up the metaclass? Or just defining a class method?

Tags: ruby

I am reading the Stripe API and I see this:

```
module Stripe

  ...

  class << self
    attr_accessor :stripe_account, :api_key, :api_base, :verify_ssl_certs, :api_version, :connect_base, :uploads_base,
                  :open_timeout, :read_timeout

    attr_reader :max_network_retry_delay, :initial_network_retry_delay
  end
```

What is going on there? I tried reading Yehuda Katz's blog on this, but parts of it are kind of unclear, like this:

What is going on in the two examples he provides?

> It turns out that all of these weird rules collapse down into a single
>   concept: control over the self in a given part of the code. Let's go
>   back and take a look at some of the snippets we looked at earlier:

```
class Person     
   def name
      "Matz" 
   end

  self.name #=> "Person" 
end
```

> Here, we are adding the name method to
>   the Person class. Once we say `class Person`, the self until the end of
>   the block is the `Person` class itself.

```
Person.class_eval do     
   def name
       "Matz"
   end

   self.name #=> "Person"
end
```

> Here, we're doing exactly the same
>   thing: adding the name method to instances of the `Person` class. In
>   this case, `class_eval` is setting the self to Person until the end of
>   the block. This is all perfectly straight forward when dealing with
>   classes, but it's equally straight forward when dealing with
>   metaclasses:

Why does Yehuda keep writing:

`self.name #=> "Person"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "class method" in Ruby. All methods are *instance* methods. Thing is just that instances are different.

`Stripe` is an instance of class `Module`, and `Person` is an instance of class `Class`.

So in your first example (`Stripe`) there is a definition of `attr_accessor`s available to object `Stripe`.

So you will be able to read and write `Stripe`s attributes:

```
Stripe.api_key = :some_key
Stripe.api_key
#=> :some_key
```

While the following defines a method available to instances of class `Person`

```
Person.class_eval do
  def name
    "Matz"
  end
end
```

You could have defined instance method available to `Person` class by using [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), which evaluated the code within the context of the receiver:

```
Person.instance_eval do
  def name
    "Matz"
  end
end
Person.name # this is what they sometimes called  "a class method", which I don't like personally
#=> 'Matz'
```

It is always just a matter of a context. Once you understand what `self` is and where `self` points at any moment - things will become so much clearer.

Comment: @Jwan622 because it is a context of `Person`. As i said, it is always a matter of `self`. Inside the body of the class you are in the context of that class, meaning that `self` points to the class itself. It is the same as if you'd write `Person.name` outside the class definition

Comment: oh `name` is a built-in function it seems.

Comment: @Jwan622 [here are docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-name) for `name` method